# How to make a long text horizontally scrollable to avoid Renderflex overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

As you can see in my application, the second `Text()` widget is too long and overflows the screen.
What I wanna implement is to have an animation on that `Text()` that automatically scrolls horizontally and continuously, so that the user can read it.

Note that the animation should be implemented only on the widgets that overflows the screen (in my case on the second text widget).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {/* do something */},
  child: Container(
    width: 500.0,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Icon(icon),
        const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        Text(title, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Text` widget in a `SingleChildScrollView` such as:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 child: Text(
   'Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very long string',
  ),
)
```

In your case, you can wrap the `Row` with `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Same-same answer, not sure who posted first, you or me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any third party package and need a simple horizontal scrollable widget, you can just wrap your `Row` in a `SingleChildScrollView`, something like this:

[image]

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(veryLongText),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much but this isn't working, first, you should wrap your `SingleChildScrollView()` with `Expanded()`, otherwise it will give an error,  and what I wanna implement is to let the text AUTOMATICALLY scrolls ONLY WHEN THE TEXT TOO LARGE IS

Comment: @arrmani88 No, it will not give you an error as I'm not using `SingleChildScrollView` in any of the flex widgets so I don't need to wrap it in either `Expanded` or `Flexible`. I understand you needed marquee effect, so surely this question doesn't answer the content of your post but it does answer the title you posted. So, if you intend to change the title of your post, I'll delete my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with `SingleChildScrollView` to make it scrollable and then wrap it with `Expanded` to get available size.

```dart
InkWell(
    onTap: () {/* do something */},
    child: Container(
      width: 500.0,
      child: Row(
        children: const [
          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              // primary: false, // may needed
              child: Text(
                "title lonmggggggggggggssssssssssasdasdaasdasds323423sss756g",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I want to apply animation only on widgets, that will overflow the layouts, and the animation should scroll automatically and infinitely

Comment: Animate  to end?